# openid connect provider and client example in django

Tags: python, django, openid-connect

I need to build a Django web-app. My web-app needs to support authentication and authorization using OpenID Connect. It is my first time doing this. Is there a free Identity Provider to test my application or do I need to write the provider and the  client? My task is to write only the client that connects to the provider. An example would be great or some course/tutorial I can use to learn how to do this.
Maybe there are no good examples in Django but I know ASN.NET and Java so those examples could inspire me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of OpenID Connect providers you can use to test your client: you can sign up for a free Auth0 or Okta developer sandbox, download and run [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) locally, or try the [OAuth2 Playground](https://www.oauth.com/playground/).

As for writing the client. Please don't write your own. There are a list of libraries from the [OpenId Foundation](https://openid.net/developers/libraries/). I've used [pyoidc](https://github.com/OpenIDC/pyoidc) for a non Django application, you could hook that in to your app, or use one of the Django specific OpenID Connect libraries.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this example using both provider (django app using `django-oidc-provider` package) and client (using JS).

https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/examples.html

Comment: disclaimer: he's the author of the linked library